# PHP encoding issue

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a trouble displaying Cyrillic characters properly. Looked in forums, tried a few different thing and nothing works.

Site runs on PHP / MySQL.

MySQL tables charset is utf8, and collation is utf8_general_ci
Name entry in DB looks correct (in PhpmyAdmin): 
Sasha Рукина

Output on page http://www.sodaq.com/: Sasha ??????

Inside PHP I use:

mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
mb_http_output("UTF-8");

And send HTTP header 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'

Still, shows '????' instead of normal characters.

Please help.

Comment: not sure about this but did you check whether the browser has the encoding installed already?

Comment: Sure you don't have a browser problem? The text at that link renders correctly here, and the document is being correctly detected as UTF-8.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: @zerocrates, it wasn't browser, I sure tried that. I added SET NAMES and SET CHARACTER_SET to utf8 and it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to execute the following query before loading your data

```
SET NAMES 'utf8';
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you also tried:

```
set character_set_connection=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the font you're using, but it's a big factor. Not all fonts contain all character sets.

Comment: Font didn't matter. All I end up doing was converting tables to UTF-8 and adding mysql_query ("SET NAMES utf8"); mysql_query ("SET CHARACTER_SET utf8"); to MySQL connect code in PHP